# .Net Core OData enable filtering for single entity set

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, odata, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm running the Beta of OData on .Net Core.  I'm trying to only enable certain features of odata depending on the controller.  My startup class looks like so:

```
services.AddOData();   
//...

app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
{
    //routeBuilder.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select().MaxTop(null);
    routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", null, GetModel());
    routeBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection();
});

public static IEdmModel GetModel()
{
    var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    var skillSet = builder.EntitySet<Skill>(nameof(Skill));
    skillSet.EntityType.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select();
    builder.Namespace = "ODataTest.Models";
    builder.ContainerName = "DefaultContainer";

    return builder.GetEdmModel();
}
```

When I globally enable odata everything works fine.  However, I cannot expose all of my entities

```
routeBuilder.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select().MaxTop(null);
```

but when, I try to enable odata for a specific entity set my I get an error when I attempt to filter

```
skillSet.EntityType.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select();
```

> The query specified in the URI is not valid. The property 'Name' cannot be used in the $filter query option.

For the sake of completeness here is my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[EnableQuery]
public async Task<Skill[]> GetFilteredODataList(ODataQueryOptions<Skill> q)
{
    var skillsQuery = this._context.Skills.AsQueryable();
    if (q?.Filter != null)
    {
        skillsQuery = q.Filter.ApplyTo(skillsQuery, new ODataQuerySettings()) as IQueryable<Skill>;
    }

    return await skillsQuery.ToArrayAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if your issue could be solved by the way ModelBuilder.cs is built [in my SO question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49881133/asp-net-core-ef-odata-v4-core-beta-2) In that page you should be able to define per entity what OData settings are permitted.

The article I link to in the first paragraph will explain it better than I did as that was what I was following.